# How can I convert List<int>data array to something that I could use for bitmasking?

Tags: c#, bit, bitmask

I have a `List<int>data` like that(it is JSON representation of list):

```
     "data":[0, 0, -1, -1]
```

I assume it means 1100(in binary)??
How can I convert it(`[0, 0, -1, -1]`) to something that I could use for bitmasking?

Comment: Bitmask with other that 0 and 1??

Comment: An int is already a bitmask. If you want to tweak the bits, you can use bitwise operators freely on ints. If you want to convert the int to an enum that has the Flags attribute, a cast will work

Comment: @JohnB this binary data represents 1 mask, so how can I convert it from binary stored as int to int?

Comment: If question is not clear please tell me :)

Comment: ah, ok i did not understand it was `binary` stored as `int`

Comment: Ok, I will look it up. I will keep this up for now if it won't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitmasking can be done with int data type (or its variants int16/int32/int64). If you are getting these bitmasks as string in JSON, then get that first in List and below code will convert List into bitmask in integer. This integer 'mask' value can then be used bit masking with & ,| bitwise operators.

```
        int mask = 0;
        List<int> data = new List<int>() { 1, 1, 0, 1 };
        //Here you can iterate list from Left to Right or from Right to Left as per your need
        foreach(int i in data)
            mask = (mask << 1)|i;

        //Bit mask in ready in mask integer
```

~Nilesh